# Setting yaxis as logarithmic with Highcharts cakephp plugin

Tags: cakephp, highcharts

I'm using a plugin for cakephp. https://github.com/destinydriven/cakephp-high-charts-plugin

The issue I'm having is that I'm attempting to report on revenue from different product lines, the difference between them can be enormous.  So when I have this revenue I can't display it on a column chart unless I divide the sums by 1000. This is ugly, it's wrong and I hate it.  A much better sounding solution would be to use highcharts y-axis.type and set this as logarithmic.

The issue I'm having is that it doesn't appear to have this functionality in this library.  So does anyone know how to add this, if I'm wrong and this does have the functionality, or a better solution to my yaxis problems?

Thanks,
Bmckie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checked their code, and they only set xAxis type (using `xAxisType`), yAxis' type is not supported.

You can add this on your own, this way:

- navigate file: Controller/Component/HighChartsComponent.php
- go to line: ~516, below comment: `// Y axis options`
- add this lines:

  ```
  if (isset($params['yAxisType'])) {
      $this->charts[$name]->yAxis->type = $params['yAxisType'];
  }
  ```

Note: It's not tested, I'm not PHP guy. But this should allow you setting `yAxisType` param, like 'logarithmic'.

Comment: Thank you for looking into it; I also tried a solution like this before posting the question.  This alone doesn't work but I think if I keep going into the architecture of the plugin I can find how to get that working.  At least I know I was on the right track.

Comment: Somewhere in the code I saw HighRoller. Maybe HighRoller is missing yAxis.type option?

Comment: I forget what I did because I had to do a lot of talking after I got it to work, but the scale is logarithmic(wrong, but log'd) and I'll add what it was when I remember. Thank you. Edit: It needed to go after line 557 when yAxis was instantiated as a HighRollerAxisTitle object

Answer (score 0):

You can set it to log:

```
yAxis: {
    type: 'logarithmic'
}
```

See the API [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.type).

Comment: I know the attribute to set; the issue I'm having is with the plugin, I can't figure out either where to put this in the files, or how to set this with calls to the plugin.

Comment: Well, read that question wrong. Sorry. Looking at the github it states this plugin is only very basic.